# How to set Kendo Grid's total count manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

i am trying to set total count value of Grid  manually on delete event.When delete button pressed, delete event is catched by javascript , pass value that will be delete. At last, i would like to decrease total count of grid.Problem is, i am able to decrease count but i dont know how to set new count to grid's Datasource as total value.

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>() 
   .Name("grid")
    .Events(e=>e.Remove("customDelete"))
```

**JS**

```
    e.preventDefault();

    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
    var count = grid.total();
    alert(count); // actual count

    var countNew=  grid.total() - 1  //new count after delete  ;
    alert(countNew);
    //...  need to set grid's total count as countNew

    $('.k-pager-info').html(1 + " - " + countNew+  " of " + countNew+ " items");
    var data = e.model["ID"]; // Getting IDvalue of column
    ...// Deleting process
```

Comment: Isn't total count updated Automatically by the Grid? Check the demo here http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/editing-inline.html

Comment: If i catch the delete event and set "e.preventDefault();" , count doesn't refresh automatically after deleting column.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @PeturSubev, if you delete the row it should automatically be decremented. If for some sort of reason -that I cannot understand- you need to set it to some value, the solution is implement a custom `total` function in the [`schema.model`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.total). Something like:

```
var countNew = undefined;
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        /* transport configuration */
    }
    schema: {
        total: function (d) {
             return countNew || d.length;
        }
    }
});

// Compute newCount with as you want
var countNew =  grid.total() - 1  // new count after delete  ;
```

Comment: in customDelete function(remove event), it doesnt' refresh the total count automatically after delete a row value.But it removes the column visually.I dont want to refresh datasource everytime after delete a single column that is why i am trying to refresh total count value visually.

Comment: So it is like a batch update, correct? Do you know about DataSource batch http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-batch?

Comment: Batch was set to false as default.If i turn on batch editing , i need to edit almost all action methods on controller.It is easier to add hidden textbox ,set it's value to grid's total count,and decrease it's count everytime delete function runs.But i would like to do it by grid's native functions.